# Как развернуть див частично?

Tags: javascript, jquery

я имею

```
<div id="2" class="slider">
    <div class="wow-ggg">1</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">2</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">3</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">4-1</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">5-2</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">6-3</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">7-4</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">8-5</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">9-1</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">10-2</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">11-3</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">12-4</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">90-5</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">100</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">таких много</div>
</div>
```

Мне нужно чтобы изначально при загрузке страницы **div id="2" class="slider"**
был свернут
и былo показанo только **N** элементов **.wow-ggg**  (допустим три), а ниже была кнопочка ПОКАЗАТЬ ЕЩЕ,
И при нажатии показывалось не все сразу остальное а только **K** элементов **.wow-ggg**  (допустим пять) и при наличии непоказанных элементов эта кнопочка(ПОКАЗАТЬ ЕЩЕ../..свернуть все ..) оставалась пока все элементы не будут показаны, а в коне только  - ..свернуть все ...

Кнопку показать еще не могу вставить в разметку `<div id="more">Показать ещё</div>`,    я могу это сделать только через .slider:after {
content: "Показать еще";
}

У меня есть такая конструкция https://jsfiddle.net/profy/xwosnjfu/201/ , но это кончено не совсем то что нужно, но которую я через CSS (скрол например) сделаю что-то похожее что мне нужно, ..... может найдется добрая душа для решения вышеописанной задачи, в сложных скриптах я не силен.
Спасибо.

Comment: Вы можете менять JS, но не можете менять разметку? Как так?

Comment: @Sevastopol: даже, если и выводит, то не отслеживает изменения. Потому createElement и вперёд :)

Answer (score 1):

> Кнопку показать еще не могу вставить в разметку `<div id="more">Показать ещё</div>`, я могу это сделать только через
> .slider:after { content: "Показать еще"; }

Если нет возможности вносить изменения в `HTML`, то можно же создать новый элемент (кнопку) посредством JavaScript. И фактически она у нас будет в HTML-документе. Пример:

```js
var value = true
var more = document.createElement('button');
var textInBtnMore = document.createTextNode('Показать еще');
more.classList.add("more");
more.appendChild(textInBtnMore);
if (value) {
  document.body.appendChild(more);
}

var data = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.wow-ggg')),
  item = 0,
  step = 4;
item += step;
data.slice(step).forEach(e => e.style.display = 'none');
document.querySelector('.more').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var tmp = data.slice(item, item + step);
  tmp.forEach(ee => ee.style.display = 'block');
  item += step;
  if (tmp.length < 4)
    this.remove();
});
```

```css
.slider {display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; height: 24px; padding: 6px 0;}
.wow-ggg {margin: 1px; padding: 3px; background-color: lightgray;}
```

```html
<div id="2" class="slider">
  <div class="wow-ggg">01</div>
  <div class="wow-ggg">02</div>
  <div class="wow-ggg">03</div>
  <div class="wow-ggg">04</div>
  <div class="wow-ggg">05</div>
  <div class="wow-ggg">06</div>
  <div class="wow-ggg">07</div>
  <div class="wow-ggg">08</div>
  <div class="wow-ggg">09</div>
  <div class="wow-ggg">10</div>
  <div class="wow-ggg">11</div>
  <div class="wow-ggg">12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: огромное спасибо , но как вы сами сказали Ж)), не помешала бы кнопочка "скрыть всё" , да я понимаю что можно через js добавить все кнопки , но хотелось бы использовать css чтоб неподгружатся лишней строкой скипта

Comment: ну кнопочка скрытия должна соответственно скрывать то что мы открывали, тока не по N элементов которые мы раскрывали, а все раскрытые сразу...:).... мне кажется это очевидно..:)